# How to pass Typeface(not custom font path) to another activity or store in SharedPreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-typeface

I am getting the [Typeface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html) as a parameter from the integrating application to my SDK.
How can I store it in SharedPrefrences or pass to another Activity?

The integrating application can send the inbuilt typeface like [Typeface.SERIF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#SERIF) or they can create a custom typeface using `Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontAssetPath)`

So, how can I use the given Typeface in different places of my SDK?

Comment: Why can't you use the path?

Comment: Then how the integrating app can use the Typeface.SERIF(inbuilt typefaces instead of custom)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I store it in SharedPrefrences

You can't. You would have to store enough information to re-create the `Typeface`.

> or pass to another Activity?

You can't. You would have to pass enough information to allow the other activity re-create the `Typeface`.

Comment: What are the enough information needed to recreate the Typeface & how can I use the given Typeface in different places of my SDK

Comment: @VigneshSundar: "What are the enough information needed to recreate the Typeface" -- you are going to have to create the `Typeface` instances yourself, so you have the data to recreate them. For built-in ones, you would invent your own identifier system, so you can hold onto the identifier (e.g., an integer) and know how to get the system-supplied `Typeface` back from the identifier. "how can I use the given Typeface in different places of my SDK" -- since I do not know what your SDK is or how it is implemented, I cannot answer that.